# Spark Conf Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Please excuse the novice question first and foremost as I am trying to learn spark and scala in intellij.

I added in the dependency below for my build.sbt and it compiles fine.

```
name := "learning project"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.1.0"
```

However, when I go and create my scala class and when I try to import

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark._
```

it shows me an error saying symbols not found.

I check my libraries for my project and the sbt: org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.11:2.1.0:jar file is there.

Hence I am unsure what I am doing wrong

Comment: could you provide more information- is this on github?

Comment: Hi Steve, thank you so much . I have added in my repo here: https://github.com/leeadh/scalalearning.git

Comment: no problem, if you want an example here is a small project I wrote recently https://github.com/sblack4/streaming-data-analytics-demo/tree/master/bdc-spark-scala

Comment: try cleaning your project and package using sbt clean package

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `sbt clean` and maybe deleting the `.idea` folder and re-importing the project

also, try this code,

```
import org.apache.spark._

object WordCount {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val conf = new SparkConf()
      .setAppName("Simple Application")
      .setMaster("local")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val lines = sc.textFile("src/main/resources/word_count.text").cache()
    val wordCounts = lines.flatMap(line => line.split(" "))
      .map(word => (word, 1))
      .reduceByKey((a, b) => a + b)

    for ((word, count) <- wordCounts)
      println(word + " : " + count)
    sc.stop()
  }
}
```

I hope that clarifys things :)

Comment: Hi Steve! firstly thank you so much once again for your help:). 

I am a little unclear when u mean the structure isnt according to SBT directions - I followed this guide previously when i created my project. The only thing which I didnt do was to create the package which I have done so and put my wordcount.scala class inside but its still not working.

Comment: Hello! thank you for this steven. I have merged and git pulled but sbt just keeps showing its syncing. I then reimported the project. but still its showing as syncing.

Comment: so it just syncs indefinately?

Comment: Hi Steven yes it just syncs indefinitely.

Comment: Did you try deleting the ‘.idea’ folder?

Comment: Try adding set logLevel := Level.Debug to your build.sbt

Comment: the .idea folder is not visible in mac sadly. I am trying in windows now

Comment: It’s still there, just hidden, try deleting it with the terminal